# Redirect file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm building a website in PHP where I have split up the project in two parts, the api and the "web application". The api is accessed at `http://api.localhost` and the other part at `http://localhost`.

Now on `http://localhost` I've added a [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) form but I want to handle the request at `http://api.localhost/upload`. Since it's different domains, dropzone doesn't seem to allow it out of the box.

Can I upload the file to `http://localhost` and somehow redirect the file to `http://api.localhost/upload`? Or is there something else I can try?

Comment: Can you allow the upload to take place on the web application?

On the back end, using internal networking (if the infrastructure will be similar once going live), just connect to the api server and copy the file over along with some sort of unique identifier to tie it all together..

Comment: with php, no. during file uploads, php code doesn't execute until AFTER the upload completes (successful or otherwise). so you can't stream the upload to the other server WHILE it's uploading, only afterwards. you can also not have one single http request go to two different urls at the same time.

Comment: Best case would be to fix whatever is preventing dropzone from using your api url (likely just means properly implementing CORS, which is relatively easy in most cases.)